# Page Replacement and LRU

Tags: operating-system, lru

If a page fault occured, then  we have to replace the least recently used page of the process that request the frame or we have to replace the page that is   least recently used all over the main memory?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Theory**

Assume that there are N pages of data, which includes:

- all data belonging to all processes
- all file data on disk (that could be pre-fetched into a virtual file system cache)
- all DNS lookup information (that could be pre-fetched into some kind of DNS cache)
- all static HTML pages, images, etc (that could be pre-fetched into some kind of web page cache)
- anything else you could possibly pre-fetch before software could want it
- all data that can be pre-generated by software (e.g. things like prime number sieves, cached pixel data generated from fonts, mipmaps, ...)

The goal is to fill RAM with the "most likely to be needed next" data from all possible sources. Note that this can include (e.g.) sending recently used data belonging to a process from RAM to swap space so that you can use that RAM to pre-fetch data from the internet that has not been requested (if you know the data is more likely to be needed sooner than the data from the process).

There are 3 major problems:

- some of the data is controlled by normal processes and not the OS; and there's no standard way of allowing normal processes to participate in the operating system's "keep RAM filled with the most likely to be needed next data" scheme.
- often you can't accurately predict the future. Note that you can look at things like when a process will wake up after calling "`sleep()`" to accurately predict a tiny part of the future; and you can track statistics to inaccurately predict other things (e.g. if you know that the user checked a certain web site at lunch time on 9 of the previous 10 days then you can predict that there's a 90% chance they will check that web site at lunch time today). Of course (for some cases) "most recently used" is a reasonable predictor of "most likely to be needed again soon"; which leads to "keep the most recently used in RAM", which is where "evict the least recently used" (LRU) comes from.
- there is cost associated with transferring data, where the cost depends on where the data is now and how busy the hardware needed to fetch the data currently is (e.g. fetching data from a fast Internet connection might be cheap when the network card is doing nothing anyway but expensive when the network card is busy doing a lot of other stuff)

**Practice**

You can try to solve all the problems (e.g. keep track of lots of things and have fancy prediction algorithms; and take the cost of transferring and/or generating data into account when deciding what to do; and provide some kind of "current memory pressure notification" that normal processes can use to participate in the operating system's "keep RAM filled with the most likely to be needed data" scheme); but it's all complicated and difficult (e.g. you'd want to ensure that the overhead of figuring out what should/shouldn't be in RAM doesn't cost more performance than you gain), so operating systems often do something much simpler and less effective.

Specifically; a very simple OS might only do "evict the least recently used" (with no pre-fetching, no consideration for the cost of transfers and and without normal processes participating at all); and this might be considered "good enough" despite being horribly bad.

> If a page fault occured, then we have to replace the least recently used page of the process that request the frame or we have to replace the page that is least recently used all over the main memory?

Ideally, you'd try to evict the "least likely to be needed soon" data from all of memory (possibly including data belonging to the kernel itself); but compromises are unavoidable and there's nothing to say a "good enough despite being horribly bad" OS can't just evict the least recently used page from the current process.